# Text is not shown on DotNetBar button when imagePosition is set to left

Tags: c#, dotnetbar

I use DotNetBar 9.3. When I create a button in a `RibbonBar`, after I import an image to this button, I want to set the image position to the left of the text of the button.  However, when I set the `imagePosition` property to Left, the text is not shown.  How can I set the image position and still show the text?

Answer (score 4):

After searching the net for a couple of hours, I just found 1 question that is the same with my question and it is yours.. But failed to find an answer.

After exploring the button properties, I found the answer...

I just change the ButtonStyle Properties to ImageAndText, it is in Default (which I don't know if text or image only), and Hoola!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you need to do. Change ButtonStyle to include both image and text.

Comment: I come from the future and you saved me. Thanks!